# Delete button functionality

Tags: java, swing

I had developed the below window.

[image]

I want to develop the DELETE functionality. While clicking the DELETE button, the corresponding TextField should be removed from the window.
I will attached the design code below - Only for the `Add More Files` button action.
While clicking the `Add More Files` button, another TextField and DELETE button is creating and adding to the `headerpanel`. S I have no way to connect these TextField and Button(in the same Line). I know this is not the correct format of developing this type windows.

How can I design(or redesign) to meet the DELETE functionality?

`Add More Files` Action code:

```
cAttach.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                File file = null;
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(EMailDialog.this);
                if ((returnVal == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION))
                {

                    attachments.add(fc.getSelectedFile());
                    file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    fieldPosition += 5;
                    CTextField cFileNew = new CTextField();
                    headerPanel.add(cFileNew, new GridBagConstraints(0, fieldPosition,
                            5, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.EAST,
                            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(7, 80, 5,
                                    185), 0, 0)); // Text field
                    //thush
                    CButton  cDelete= new  CButton("Delete"); 
                    headerPanel.add(cDelete, new GridBagConstraints(0, fieldPosition , 5,
                            1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, 
                            new Insets(7, 425, 5, 105), 0, 0)); // thush

                    cFileNew.setText("" + file);
                    listOfTextFields.add(cFileNew);
                    headerPanel.updateUI();
                    mainPanel.updateUI();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i want to build tower on moon

Comment: @OpenJDK Show us your moontower code and we'll try and help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: BTW - I'd add the files to a `JList` and provide a nice renderer (that shows the file icon).  It would be much easier then, to design a single `Delete Selected` button..

Answer (score 2):

You have a way to connect them. Just keep/store them them in e.g. a `HashMap`
where each `Button` is mapped to its corresponding `TextField`. When the `Button`
gets a click, just do a lookup in your `HashMap`, pull the respective `TextField`
and do with it whatever is needed.

Comment: So my button and text field declaration should be outside the action listener of `Add More Files` button. But in this case I am declaring and defining both inside the ActionListener of  `Add More Files` button. That was done because 'n' number of files may need to attach.

Comment: @Thush not quite. The `Map<JButton, JTextField> map = new Hashmap<>()` declaration is outside of the action listener scope. Inside `actionPerformed()`, a new button + textfield is created and both are added to the Hashmap: `map.put(myButton, myTextField)`.

Comment: @Thush Create the HashMap instance at some "global" (don't take this literally) level e.g. the HashMap can be an instance member. Add the objects (buttons, text fields) to that HashMap when you create them.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is a good use case for combining [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [setClientProperty(key, value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) / [getClientProperty(key)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty-java.lang.Object-) in order to anonymize the action itself as much as possible.

Let me explain a little: you need to add a pair of text field-delete button every time you attach a new file, right? The action to be performed when you press the delete button is always the same: remove both the button and the associated text field from its parent container (I guess it's `headerPanel`). This is what I'd do:

1) Define a single and common action as follows. This action should be attached to all delete buttons.

```
final Action deleteAction = new AbstractAction("Delete") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        JTextField textField = (JTextField)button.getClientProperty("AssociatedTextField");
        if (textField != null) {
            JComponent parentContainer = (JComponent)button.getParent();
            parentContainer.remove(button);
            parentContainer.remove(textField);
            parentContainer.revalidate();
            parentContainer.repaint();
            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(parentContainer).pack();
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see this action is intended to be attached to a button and looks for `AssociatedTextField` client property. If the value retrieved by this request is not null then removes both button and associated text field from the parent container, revalidates the components hierarchy and finally packs the frame.

2) To make the previous code work properly you have to add the text field to the button client properties map as follows:

```
cAttach.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        ...
        CTextField cFileNew = new CTextField();
        ...
        CButton cDelete = new  CButton(deleteAction);
        cDelete.putClientProperty("AssociatedTextField", cFileNew);
        ...
    }
});
```

Note the button is created using the Action defined in the previous step.

3) Finally you don't have to call `updateUI` (this method doesn't do what you think it does) but revalidate the components hierarchy and pack the frame in order to reflect the changes:

```
cAttach.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        ...
        headerPanel.revalidate();
        headerPanel.repaint();
        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(headerPanel).pack();
    }
});
```